# Feature attributes won't update

Tags: arcgis-server, fields-attributes, arcgis-rest-api, update, feature-service

I am trying to update feature attributes from a .NET application that I'm working on.
I've cleaned the code down to the following example:

```
string serviceUrl = string.Format("http://***.cloudapp.net/arcgis/rest/services/{0}/{1}/FeatureServer", "***", "Test");  
string featureUrl = string.Format("{0}/{1}", serviceUrl, "0");  
var table = await ServiceFeatureTable.OpenAsync(new Uri(featureUrl));  
if (table.IsInitialized)  
{  
var found = await table.QueryAsync(1);  
    if (found != null)  
    {  
        found.Attributes["testtext"] = "test";  
        await table.UpdateAsync(found);  
        if (table.HasEdits)  
        {  
            var result = await table.ApplyEditsAsync();  
        }  
    }  
}
```

It finds the feature with OBJECTID = 1, `table.HasEdits` is true after the update, and the result variable contains a ResultItem in the `UpdateResults` property, with no errors and `Success = true`.

So no errors and no indication something went wrong, but the attribute table in ArcGIS doesn't change at all. If I try to change the geometry of the feature, by adding a line like this:

```
found.Geometry = new Polygon(new List<MapPoint> { new MapPoint(0, 0), new MapPoint(-5, 0), new MapPoint(-5, -5), new MapPoint(0, -5), new MapPoint(0, 0) });
```

It will update the geometry correctly... but still no update to the other attributes of the feature.

The feature class in question here, has a field called "testtext" which is of type "Text". I've also tried fields with type short, double, date etc, but I'm still not able to update or add any attribute data.

Any clues as to what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer while using Wireshark to look at the web request being sent to ArcGIS server. It never sent any attribute updates, until I put the fields I tried to update into table.OutFields..